# How to get info from file into a string on Python?

Tags: python, xml, file

I have opened a file on Python. The file is loaded with information following this format:

```
    <weight>220</weight>
```

I have used the split function so I only get 220, which is what I wanted. Now I am trying to get each line of information put into their own string. For example, since this weight info is the 6th line, I want it to say

```
    "The weight of this player is 220 pounds."
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure where to even start. Would anyone be able to push me in the right direction?? Thank you!

```
    def summarizeData(filename):
        with open("Pro.txt","r") as fo:
             for rec in fo:
                 print (rec.split('>')[1].split('<')[0])
```

Comment: I would recommend using an XML parser rather than just dumping `str.split`s everywhere. As for what you're trying to achieve, Google "python string interpolation", you have several options and this is a really basic thing covered in any halfway-decent tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way to do this would be to use an XML parser just like johnsharpe said so your code would be something like:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("Pro.txt")
weights = tree.find("weight")
```

Then once you have the weights variable set just loop through and show your string format however you want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would reccommend you use an XML parser such as [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

However in regards to your code you are taking a positional argument `filename` in `summarizeData` but not using it... Try something like this:

```
def summarizeData(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as fo:
        for rec in fo:
            weight_of_player = rec.split('>')[1].split('<')[0]
            print("The weight of this player is %s pounds." % (weight_of_player))

summarizeData("Pro.txt")
```